# Creating Inject decorator for module that's registered multiple times

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to create a module with a service and would like to create a custom Inject decorator for it.

Let's call the Module a `Store` module, which provides and exports a `StoreService` and has to have a name. This is the Module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { StoreService } from './store.service'; 

@Module({})
export class StoreModule {
  static register(
    name: string,
  ): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: StoreModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: STORE_NAME,
          useValue: name,
        },
        StoreService,
      ],
      controllers: [],
      exports: [StoreService],
    };
  }
}
```

The 'name' is what makes the store unique.
Now I'd like to create a decorator that fetches the store by name, like `@InjectStore(name)`. I've tried to create a token based on the name, like `STORE_SERVICE_${name}` and injecting that, but the StoreModule needs to be registerred globally for that.

When I set `global: true`, it causes weird behaviour inside the module itself. Because `StoreService` is registered multiple times for multiple stores. For example, when I have a store `cats` and a store `dogs`, and I create a service inside the module and inject the store via `constructor(private readonly store: StoreService)`, it'll get one of the two.

---

A workaround for this behaviour is probably to use the `@InjectStore` decorator, but because I came across this behaviour, I'm wondering if I'm missing something or if there's a better solution, because I want to make sure it injects the right store.

I've searched far and wide for an example implementation in NestJS modules, but just couldn't find what I was looking for.

Thanks in advance!